# How I can achieve next color overlap my footer?

Tags: html, css, frontend

How I can achieve next color overlap my footer with selectable footer text? Image what I try to achive:
[image]

Additianal question: Now I can do this (text not selectable) with absolute positioned div with background png image (60% opacity), but maybe is more correct way look to svg, canvas?

Comment: I think a simple Image like a **PNG**, **JPEG**, **SVG**, or **GIF** would work for you here. It's not more *"correct"* to use canvas or some complex technology for something as simple as a static image. If infact you wanted to animate this light source then other methods ( something like canvas or svg as you suggested ) would be appropriate to be considered.

Comment: @basement thx for quickly reply, but how I can achive selectable text on footer ? Div with my image have higher z-index than footer.

Comment: Your text has to appear later in the HTML or have a higher z-index than your footer in order to appear on top. I can make an example for kicks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a dynamic light effect that expands with the text. This is one way to achieve that. The JavaScript is only present to show the animation that the div container and effect can expand to the size of the inner paragraph.

I'm using a rotated pseudo element on the div to get the slanted line. It's absolutely positioned to always stay a certain width from the right edge of the container. The container has `overflow: hidden` to keep the effect together.

```js
var str = '<p>footer with text ( pinned to bottom )</p>',
    i = 0,
    isTag,
    text;

( function type() {
    text = str.slice( 0, ++i );
    if ( text === str ) return;
    
    document.querySelector( 'div' ).innerHTML = text;

    var char = text.slice( -1 );
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

    if ( isTag ) return type();
    setTimeout( type, 80 );
}() );
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 6rem;
  background-color: #f80;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
}
p {
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  padding-right: 0;
  background-color: #eb8;
  color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: #eb8;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate( 45deg );
  top: 1rem;
  right: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  html, 
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <p>
    footer with text ( pinned to bottom )
  </p>
</div>
```

**Update:** *If all you want to do is be able to select text underneath an element on top with a higher `z-index` you can use `pointer-events: none;` in the CSS on the higher z-indexed element to ignore all mouse events on the top layered element and let the text underneath react to the cursor through the element on top as if it wasn't there.*

Comment: Sorry for a long response, you answer very help me, thank you.